# Вложенная фильтрация JavaScript

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть массив объектов типа

```
data = {
  cat: 'Подгузник', //Пеленка
  prod: 'Производитель1', // Производтель2 / Производитель3
  type: 'Большие' // Маленькие, UltraSlim
}
```

Мне нужно вывести кнопки для фильтра, при нажатии на которые меняются ниже варианты подкатегорий
Т.е. выбрали подгузник, ниже высветилось 2 кнопки, которые совпадают с этим фильтром (Производитель 1 и 3), дальше доступные размеры уже по этим двум фильтрам.

Есть у кого идеи для алгоритма?

Ниже моя ужасная попытка:

```
function showDataSort(){
    let i = 0
    let filters = {}
    let copy = goods
    for(let key of keys) {
        if(key == 'articul') continue
        else if(key == 'price') continue
        var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters)
        if(filterKeys.length > 0){
            for(let fkey of filterKeys){
                copy = copy.filter(e => e[fkey] == filters[fkey])
            }
        }
        filters[key] = []
        if(i == 0){
            let j = 0;
            filters[key].push(copy[0][key])

            i++
        } else {
            for(let temp of copy) {
                if(filters[key].indexOf(temp[key]) == -1) {
                    filters[key].push(temp[key])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return copy
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал решение. Может кому пригодится

```
function clearDataView(){
    let filters = {}
    let copy = goods
    for( let key of keys ) {
        if(key == 'articul') continue  // пропускаем ненужные ключи
        else if(key == 'price') continue  // пропускаем ненужные ключи
        filters[key] = []
        for( let temp of copy ){
            if(filters[key].indexOf(temp[key]) == -1) {
                filters[key].push(temp[key])
            }
        }
        copy = copy.filter(e => e[key] == filters[key][0]); // выбираем первый элемент по дефолту
    }
    console.log(filters)
    return copy
}
```

- filters содержит подфильтры, можно использовать для вывода
- copy    содержит объекты, подходящие под выбранный фильтр